# Database SQLite Application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert-update

My application doesn't insert values when I exit from the app and run it again and I have this issue with my database. I am certain that the data are stored in the first run only and I can't add data anymore. Also, I can't update in it because of this.

Can anyone help?

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "User_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "Password";
public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "Courses";
public static final String COL_1C = "ID";
public static final String COL_2C = "Course_Name";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //create first table
    String CREATE_USER_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_2+ " TEXT," + COL_3 + " TEXT" +")";


    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);

    // create second table
    String CREATE_COURSE_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + "(" + COL_1C + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_2C+ " TEXT" +")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_COURSE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    //first table
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean Inser_to_user(String name,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
    Values.put(COL_2, name);
    Values.put(COL_3, password);
    long Result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, Values);
    if (Result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean Inser_to_courses(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
    Values.put(COL_2C, name);

    long Result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, Values);
    if (Result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor showdata(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor Result=db.rawQuery("select * from" +TABLE_NAME,null);
    return Result;
}

public boolean updateuser(String id,String name,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues Values=new ContentValues();
    Values.put(COL_1,id);
    Values.put(COL_2,name);
    Values.put(COL_3,password);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME,Values,COL_1 +"=?",new String[]{Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(id))});
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It will be easy for us to help if you can show us the log from Logcat

Comment: @MDDanishAnsari when i run it again it and insert other data  it tell me the data inserted but when  i open my database i don't see the latest data that inserted

Comment: I think it's happening because you are deleting table every time and recreating it

Comment: @MDDanishAnsari  i don't delete my table

Comment: why you are doing `Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(id))` ? `id` is already a string, why converting a string to int and then the int to string?

Comment: and you should use `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME` . SQLite returns an error if you create a table that already exists. I don´t think that this is causing your problem, but it´s not correct to do it like you do.

Comment: if your app throws an error, you should post the error log. Also, please post the part where (and how) you are using your DatabaseHelper....

Comment: @SondosAhmed how do you check the database state? Do you go through the cursor or use CLI SQLite? When you are inserting data, do you use only specified methods? Which one exactly? Does it provide you with any error in the LogCat?